# Notification not received in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm implementing a notification service and I have problems to receive the messages in Android 2.3. I receive the messages in versions 4.0 and newer but not in 2.3. In logcat appears the following errors:

Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.b.c', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.n.e.a
.
.
Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.l.a

What could be the problem? This is my method to send the notification:

```
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    MainActivity.notificationClicked = true;

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String strMessage = loadPreferences();
    String newMessage = "";

    if (!strMessage.isEmpty())
        newMessage = strMessage + "<br>" + msg;
    else
        newMessage = msg;

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, Html.fromHtml(newMessage));


    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, Html.fromHtml(msg), when);
    notification.contentView = contentView;
    String title = this.getString(R.string.app_name);


    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List < ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

    Log.d("current task :", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClass().getSimpleName());

    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

    Intent notificationIntent;

    if(!componentInfo.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.myapp")){
        notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                FirstActivity.class);
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.putExtra("login", true);
    }
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", Html.fromHtml(msg));

        oldMessage = newMessage;


        savePreferences(getApplicationContext(), oldMessage);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        int notifyID = 1;

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notifyID,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, msg, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.contentIntent = intent;

        notificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);

}
```

When I send the message I receive it in device with Android 4.2 for example but not in devices with Android 2.3. I'm debugging the app with Android 2.3 and I have put a breakpoint in the method onHandleIntent of the IntentService but it never comes. I think that it could be for the errors that appears in logcat.

How can I solve the problem for devices with Android 2.3?

Thanks in advance.

---

I change Notification to NotificationCompat:

`NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notification.contentView = contentView;

            notificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);`

but the problem persist, in logcat appears the same error

Comment: probably should use the support library to build your notification

Comment: Did you try to use NotificationCompat class for support versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I've used this in my project and it runs good. receiverActivity is activity that will open onclick, as I can remember, but I'm not 100% sure of it.

```
public static void showNotification ( Context context, Class receiverActivityClass, String title, String text, int icon )
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent( context, receiverActivityClass );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 0, intent, 0 );

        // Build notification
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder( context )
                .setContentTitle( title )
                .setContentText( text )
                .setSmallIcon( icon )
                .setContentIntent( pendingIntent )
                .setAutoCancel( true )
                .getNotification();


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                ( NotificationManager ) context.getSystemService( context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificationManager.notify( 0, notification );
    }
```